# How to create blurry effect with svg over video

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am using react with typescript. In my project, I have a video tag and over it, I have one SVG `rect` element. Now I want to do a blurry effect on SVG. I tried CSS `filter:blur(8px);` property but it's making the image completely black and not making it blur.

```
import './App.css';



const App = () => {


  return <div className='container'>
     <video autoPlay>
         <source src={'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4'} />
     </video>
<svg id="svg">
     <rect className='rectangle' x={80} y={120} width={300} height={300} />
</svg>
  </div>;
};

export default App;
```

css:

```
.rectangle{
   filter:blur(8px);
}
```

[This is I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9NhL.jpg)

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-smoke-05v5h?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: This issue likely has nothing to do with Reactjs: can you instead share a [mcve] that contains the generated markup instead?

Comment: I added sandbox link

Comment: Your sandbox example does not overlay the rectangle over the image tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some more styles to your svg:

```
.rectangle{
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

Whats more, if you need a rectangle blur, you can do this simply using `<div>`. Set the `width` and `height`, then with `position: absolute` and values of `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` place it in right posiotion.
Finally apply CSS property `backdrop-filter: blur(8px)`

Comment: Not Working. Still the effect is same

Comment: sure, try property 'fill', I edited my answer